# FBAppEvents iOS: logPurchase event reached max parameters limit, event became broken and I have no options to fix it

Tags: ios, facebook

Current production version of our application reached maximum parameters limit for logPurchase event. What can I do now to fix it?

I've tried the following:
1. Changed [FBAppEvents logPurchase:...] call to one without custom parameters. It does also failed with "(#100) Can only have up to 10 segments per event, fb_currency doesn't fit" because limit has been already reached with previous logPurchase calls.
2. Searched through App Events pages in Facebook Developers and could not find any option neither to permanent delete parameters nor delete of whole event data.
3. Updated framework SDK to last available version 3.9.

I can track purchases with some new custom event with another name like "In-App purchases" but it doesn't sound like the right way.

The best solution for such problems seems to be an option in Facebook Developers pages for permanent deletion of redundant parameters. Deletion of whole events data may not help because of existing application with bug in AppStore with large install base.

What can I do in such situation? Maybe I've missed something?